# Quicksort crashes with more than 500k elements

Tags: c

I have a problem in my pretty easy algorithm - quicksort in C.
It is very efficient (about 0.1s with randomize and checking if the list is sorted) but when i want to sort more than 500k elements it crashes. 
Unfortunatelly i need to sort more of them because i need to write some kind of summary at the end :(

Here is my code, maybe someone will see a stupid mistake.
Thanks in advance!

```
int quick (int a[],int begin,int end)
{
    int i = begin, j = end, w, q, pivot, k;
    q=begin+end;
    q=q/2;
    pivot=a[q];
    while (1)
    {
        while (a[j] > pivot && j>=0)
        j=j-1;
        while (a[i] < pivot && i<j)
        i=i+1;
        if (i < j)
        {
            k = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = k;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        return j;
    }
}

void quicks (int a[], int begin, int end)
{
    int x;
    if (end>begin)
    {
        x=quick(a,begin,end);
        quicks(a,begin,x);
        quicks(a,x+1,end);

    }
}
```

It seems that i just need to use malloc and it is working fine. Thanks a lot for Your help!

Comment: What do you mean by crashes? A seg-fault?

Comment: Do you have a stack overflow error message ? you should consider avoiding a recursive implementation.

Comment: I dont know which error message do i have :( Windows says that app stopped working. And to be honest i have few others sorting algorithms and they are all recursive

Comment: @chmike: Or using the old trick of recursing on the smaller set while looping ("tail-recursing") on the larger. 500k elements is only 20-odd stack levels once balanced.

Comment: I just realised that 5 of my others sort algorithms are also crashing with large amount of elements so i bet i just did all of them in a wrong way.

Comment: @Piotshe Recursion can be modeled by using own "stack"-variable to save "call-contexts" and a loop to iterate over it. It's a bit more lengthy but much safer code.

Comment: @user4419802 didnt know about it!
I just had to write code on my own because my teacher is very willing to accuse us of plagiarism and i bet he will be very happy to kick me out of the university

Comment: @Piotshe You may google for "iterative quicksort" to find sample implementations.

Comment: Normally the function `quick()` should return the index of the pivot placed in its final position.  This is why we should have `quicks(a,begin,x-1);`. But with your algorithm I see in my tests that in some case j is x-1 and some time not.  When you swap the pivot into a[j] you should not decrement j. Why don't you use the standard algorithm ?

Comment: Oh my God... It seems that when i use malloc all of the sorts are working well! I just need to alocate all big structures dynamically and it is fine i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from RAM exhaustion/rollover: As you use an array of *int*, each of them requires 4 bytes. Your memory mapping is handled using *size_t*-type indexes. If you are compiling in 32-bit mode (which is probably your case), the maximum number it can get at is 2147483648 (2^31). With 4 bytes per int, you can only handle 536870912 elements (2^31 / 4).

As the system requires some RAM for other purposes (e.g. globals), you can only use a bit more than 500K entries.

Solution: Use a 64-bit compiler and you should be fine.

BR

Comment: I should think that 536,870,912 elements would still provide decent headroom for 500,000 entries..

Answer (score 1):

Here is another and simpler implementation.

```
void quickSort(int a[], int begin, int end)
{
    int left = begin - 1, right = end + 1, tmp;
    const int pivot = a[(begin+end)/2];

    if (begin >= end)
        return;

    while(1)    
    {
        do right--; while(a[right] > pivot);
        do left++; while(a[left] < pivot);

        if(left < right)
        {
            tmp = a[left];
            a[left] = a[right];
            a[right] = tmp;
        }
        else 
            break;
    }
    quickSort(a, begin, right);    
    quickSort(a, right+1, end);
}
```

You call it like this

```
int main(void)
{
    int tab[5] = {5, 3, 4, 1, 2};
    int i;

    quickSort(tab, 0, 4); // 4 is index of lest element of tab

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d ", tab[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```